Pycharm меню быстрого доступа Git
Как открыть это меню быстрого доступа? Pycharm Windows 10
Вот так это меню должно выглядеть:

И мой скриншот:


можно переключится на старый ui. settings > Appearance & Behavior > New Ui. Убираем галочку. Можно правой кнопкой мыши по панельке, где располагаются все кнопки и customize toolbar, выбрать, где удобнее их расположить. Далее add action > main menu > git и далее берёшь всё что нужно

В новом интерфейсе точно такую же не получится добавить (только переключится на старый). Я у себя через меню правой кнопки -> Customize Toolbar через "+" добавляю нужные мне кнопки:

